# Simple URL GET/POST function in Python

Tags: python, http

I can't seem to Google it, but I want a function that does this:

Accept 3 arguments (or more, whatever):

- URL
- a dictionary of params
- POST or GET

Return me the results, and the response code.

Is there a snippet that does this?

Comment: The question isn't clear -- this is for a local URL, ie. you're writing a server, or a remote URL, ie. you're writing a client?

Comment: Please use more problem--descriptive titles in the future.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

**requests**

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/

Here's a few common ways to use it:

```
import requests
url = 'https://...'
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

# GET
r = requests.get(url)

# GET with params in URL
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

# POST with form-encoded data
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

# POST with JSON 
import json
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))

# Response, status etc
r.text
r.status_code
```

**httplib2**

https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2

```
>>> from httplib2 import Http
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> h = Http()
>>> data = dict(name="Joe", comment="A test comment")
>>> resp, content = h.request("http://bitworking.org/news/223/Meet-Ares", "POST", urlencode(data))
>>> resp
{'status': '200', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent',
 'server': 'Apache', 'connection': 'close', 'date': 'Tue, 31 Jul 2007 15:29:52 GMT', 
 'content-type': 'text/html'}
```

Comment: you could also use `from httplib2 import Http as h`

Comment: @3k No, he's instantiating the `Http` class, not aliasing it: `h = Http()`, not `h = Http`.

Comment: @ecstaticpeon you are very right, I must have been very tired. thanks for the correction!

Comment: It would be nice if you did this in a native way without 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 53):

Even easier: via the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) module.

```
import requests
get_response = requests.get(url='http://google.com')
post_data = {'username':'joeb', 'password':'foobar'}
# POST some form-encoded data:
post_response = requests.post(url='http://httpbin.org/post', data=post_data)
```

To send data that is not form-encoded, send it serialised as a string (example taken from the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)):

```
import json
post_response = requests.post(url='http://httpbin.org/post', data=json.dumps(post_data))
# If using requests v2.4.2 or later, pass the dict via the json parameter and it will be encoded directly:
post_response = requests.post(url='http://httpbin.org/post', json=post_data)
```

Comment: I had to wrap the post_data in json.dumps() before it worked for me: `data=json.dumps(post_data)`

Comment: @Matt, I think that this depends on whether you want to submit form-encoded data (just pass in a dict) or data that is not form-encoded (pass in a string of JSON data). I refer to the docs here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: is there any version of this module for windows?

Comment: @TheGoodUser This library (and many more) are compiled for Windows and available here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#requests

Answer (score 33):

You could use this to wrap urllib2:

```
def URLRequest(url, params, method="GET"):
    if method == "POST":
        return urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(params))
    else:
        return urllib2.Request(url + "?" + urllib.urlencode(params))
```

That will return a [Request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) object that has result data and response codes.

Comment: I prefer this one for sticking to the standard library.

Comment: should it be url + "?" instead of url + '&'?

Comment: This is nice, but to be precise, the `Request` object itself has no result data or response codes - it needs to be "requested" via a method like [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).

Comment: @Bach Do you have an example of the code that fulfills the "requested" piece like urlopen with the URLRequest method here? I can't find one anywhere.

Comment: @theJerm, I've referenced it. Try `r = urllib2.urlopen(url)` and then `r.readlines()` and/or `r.getcode()`. You may also wish to consider using [Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org) instead.

Comment: @Bach - Thanks, I downloaded the requests module and it was so much easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

```
import urllib

def fetch_thing(url, params, method):
    params = urllib.urlencode(params)
    if method=='POST':
        f = urllib.urlopen(url, params)
    else:
        f = urllib.urlopen(url+'?'+params)
    return (f.read(), f.code)


content, response_code = fetch_thing(
                              'http://google.com/', 
                              {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0}, 
                              'GET'
                         )
```

[Update]

Some of these answers are old. Today I would use the `requests` module like the answer by robaple.

Answer (score 10):

I know you asked for GET and POST but I will provide CRUD since others may need this just in case: (this was tested in [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import http.client
import json

print("\n GET example")
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("httpbin.org")
conn.request("GET", "/get")
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print(response.status, response.reason)
print(data)


print("\n POST example")
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('httpbin.org')
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
post_body = {'text': 'testing post'}
json_data = json.dumps(post_body)
conn.request('POST', '/post', json_data, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.read().decode())
print(response.status, response.reason)


print("\n PUT example ")
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('httpbin.org')
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
post_body ={'text': 'testing put'}
json_data = json.dumps(post_body)
conn.request('PUT', '/put', json_data, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.read().decode(), response.reason)
print(response.status, response.reason)


print("\n delete example")
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('httpbin.org')
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
post_body ={'text': 'testing delete'}
json_data = json.dumps(post_body)
conn.request('DELETE', '/delete', json_data, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.read().decode(), response.reason)
print(response.status, response.reason)
```