# Get List of Distinct From Nested List

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I'm brand new to Python coming over from a javascript/nodeJS upbringing. I have a python dictionary with a nested list that I'm having lots of trouble accessing. I need to pull out the nested list so I can check for unique e-mails. Here is what my `GET` request pulls back:

```
{"data": [{"login_date": "2014-04-17T19:14:29+08:00", "email": "walter.elwyn@yahoo.com"}, {"login_date": "2014-04-22T09:31:56+04:00", "email": "helyn67@cruickshankmckenzie.com"}]
```

The actual data dictionary that gets returned is much longer but you get the point... so I have two questions:

1. how do I access a specific point by e-mail in the content dictionary
2. how do I loop over the dictionary for unique emails?

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
import urllib2
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    content = urllib2.urlopen('https://9g9xhayrh5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/data').read()

    print content

        return 'check console'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: why are using a dictionary if you only have one entry?

Comment: I didn't write the API

Comment: so `content` is your dictionary?

Comment: yes, sorry should have wrote that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a structure like this:

```
>>> response = {"data": [{"login_date": "2014-04-17T19:14:29+08:00", "email": "walter.elwyn@yahoo.com"}, {"login_date": "2014-04-22T09:31:56+04:00", "email": "helyn67@cruickshankmckenzie.com"}]}
```

Then what you have is a dict with key `data`

```
>>> response['data']
[{'login_date': '2014-04-17T19:14:29+08:00', 'email': 'walter.elwyn@yahoo.com'}, {'login_date': '2014-04-22T09:31:56+04:00', 'email': 'helyn67@cruickshankmckenzie.com'}]
```

You can get a list of emails with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [user['email'] for user in response['data']]
['walter.elwyn@yahoo.com', 'helyn67@cruickshankmckenzie.com']
```

> How do I loop over the dictionary for unique emails?

To make that list unique, you can use a set comprehension:

```
>>> {user['email'] for user in response['data']} 
set(['helyn67@cruickshankmckenzie.com', 'walter.elwyn@yahoo.com'])
```

> How do I access a specific point by e-mail in the content dictionary

If you want to filter for a given email, you can use `filter()`

```
>>> filter(lambda user: user['email'] == 'walter.elwyn@yahoo.com', response['data'])
[{'login_date': '2014-04-17T19:14:29+08:00', 'email': 'walter.elwyn@yahoo.com'}]
```

> If I do content['data] in my case, I get an internal server error

That's because to do `content['data']`, `content` needs to be a dict-like object. Let's use `requests` lib to do what you want:

```
>>> import requests
>>> content = requests.get('https://9g9xhayrh5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/data')
>>> response = content.json() # reads the data as JSON, into a dict-like object
>>> response.keys()
[u'data']
```

Now you can use `response['data']`

Comment: To get unique email ids, {user['email'] for user in response['data']}

Comment: ok gotcha, but whats driving me crazy is if i do response['data']...content['data] in my case, I get an internal server error

Comment: There you go @AdamWeitzman, a working snippet using `requests` instead of `urllib2`, I hope that's okay! You might like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476373/simple-url-get-post-function-in-python/4476389#4476389

Comment: ok amazing, thank you for all the help..it seems when i use print response['data] i get a JSON printout in my terminal and an internal server error in the browswer. When I use return response['data'] i get errors all around, what is going on here?

Comment: Run your flask app with `app.run(debug=True)` and find out, I don't think the issue is related to my answer, as the snippet I pasted were ran live :)