# Accessing MongoDB Database on nodejs server using HTTP GET requests

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, http, pycurl

I have a nodejs server setup on AWS with mongoDB. I want to access the database contents using GET method. There is another application in python which needs to access this database present on AWS. I searched on the internet and came across PycURL but I am not getting how to use it exactly. How to approach with pycURL or what can be an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your restful API that is going to handle those GET requests. You have awesome tutorial (with example that you want on bottom):

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

---

Edit: If you want phyton code for GET requests there is awesome answer here: [Simple URL GET/POST function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476373/simple-url-get-post-function-in-python)

---

Edit 2: Example of how would this work. You first need to code your API how to handle GET request and on what route (example: http://localhost:5000/api/getUsers). Than you want to make GET request to that route using Phyton:
Example:

```
r = requests.get(url="http://localhost:5000/api/getUsers")
```

Comment: Actually our server is working. we have another application having python scripts and that application needs accessing the database. So how do i acess the database from that application (code in python)

Comment: @TanayNarkhede You have awesome answer written in phyton here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476373/simple-url-get-post-function-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, there is a tutorial here [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/MongoDB_PyMongo/python_MongoDB_RESTAPI_with_Flask.php). It can lead you towards your intended direction, the drawback may be that in the tutorial, to issue the http request (if I remember correctly), they used postman but I'm sure you can still use PyCurl.