# Python requests: Post form-data

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a webpage. The page has a select with many options in it. ON selecting one option, the page reloads with a table corresponding to that option. I want to scrape that table. However, the URL stays the same. The only change happens in the form data which on inspection has the value of option selected and a csrf_token. How do I replicate the behaviour in python?

My code:

```
client = requests.session()
url = "https://recruitment.advarisk.com/tests/scraping"
client.get(url)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
return csrftoken
```

Comment: As I don't want to flag your post, here's a possible answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476373/simple-url-get-post-function-in-python

Comment: @Alteus I did try that. But I get `Bad Request. CSRF token missing or incorrect`. I got the csrf value from xpath. But when I post it in data parameter it gives that error.