# Python file not appending on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, file, append, raspberry-pi4

I'm quite new to Python and Pi'ing, and would like some help with appending a text file on a Raspberry Pi. My script will call a GET or a POST REST API and write the time, status and reason for each call.

I got the call information from grepit's comment in [Simple URL GET/POST function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476373/simple-url-get-post-function-in-python) and it works great.

For appending my file, I use the following code:

```
#...Some working code...

dateNow = datetime.datetime.now()
string = ("\n" + dateNow.strftime("%c") + " - " + str(response.status) +
          ": " + response.reason + "\n")

with open('MyCallLog.txt', 'a+') as file:
    file.write(string)
```

What I have read regarding similar issues, is that the file is not closed or flushed. However, if I try to debug using `print(file.read())` outside the 'with' I get an error that is file is already closed and debugging inside the with displays nothing. I also tried it without the with and specifically stating `file.close()`. I have debugged the string variable using `print(string)` and it displays as intended.

Any suggestions?

Final notes:

- I am aware that opening a file as 'a+' does open it in read and write mode. This is currently only for my debugging purposes.

Comment: As an aside, have a look into string formatting using the `str.format()` function, and/or 'f-strings'.  This will make your string concatenation much simpler, rather than the JS format currently being used.

Comment: Without seeing the whole function or more code I can't be certain what is going on. Perhaps if your script is continuously running you are always in the context manager?

Comment: Try *just* the snippet you have above; I tried something similar (just a different string) and worked fine.  (Also on a Pi).  Just ensure you are looking at the file created in the *current* directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file is opened in append mode using `"a+"` the cursor is positioned at the end of the file. That is why a call to `.write()` will append to the end of the file instead of overwriting it.

When you call `file.read()` in the `with` block, it is reading the file from the last character onwards, which is why your print output is empty.

To print the content you need to seek to the beginning of the file.

```py
with open("myfile.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write("some_text")
    file.seek(0)
    print(file.read()) # "some_text"
```

Better yet, just open the file again for your debugging.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write("some_text")

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Your code to append was actually correct. There should be a file in the CWD with all of your attempts in it.

Also, the reason that you get an error when you try to call `.read()` outside of the `with` block is because `file.close()` is implicitly called when the block exits.

`open()` returns a **context manager**. You can read about context managers in python [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html). They are very useful and great to know about. I write new context managers often at my job.

Comment: Nice answer, and kudos for mentioning the context manager details.

Comment: Great, thanks! So I have played around a bit, and it appears to be working in the actual file, but the file.seek(0) made that I couldn't see my changes (or any previous data)